# How to build VS project with Nuget packages in Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, nuget

I Use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.2 to create Nunit tests, and use Jenkins to download, build and run tests on PC. If I build test in Visual studio, I get build with all my dependencies

[image]

If I use Jenkins (MSBuild plugin) I get build without dependencies and I can't run tests in nunit3-console

[image]

Also, if I build project in Jenkins via console command I have the same result (build without dependencies)
[image]

Here is my jenkins MSBuild settings:

[image]

What should I do to build project in Jenkins include all dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I find solution, it needs to build project via command "dotnet build"
[image]
but why msbuild does not work, I still do not understand

Comment: Yes, this is because your project is based on .NET Core. MSBuild apparently works only with .NET Framework. My project is based on .NET Core (.NET 6). I also faced issues with MSBuild but worked perfectly fine with "dotnet build <path-to-sln>". Verified this in Jenkins build as well.